# Uncaught ReferenceError: function is not defined at HTMLInputElement.onclick

Tags: javascript, html, function

I have a problem with my code, It's a currency calculator and u can store your results, and it's work fine but I also want to make it able to delete result, function removeRow should do that but when I'm trying to use I have a console error like:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: removeRow is not defined
at HTMLInputElement.onclick (index.html:1)
```

I've tried everything I found and nothing helps

Here's my code:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
console.log("DOM is ready");

const operationConfirm = document.getElementById('operationConfirm');
const resultList = document.getElementById('tableBody');

const operation = {
  euroValue: document.getElementById('euroValue'),
  operationName: document.getElementById('operationName'),
  operationValue: document.getElementById('operationValue')
}

operation.euroValue.onchange = updateValues;

operationConfirm.addEventListener("click", function() {
  let thisOperationValue = operation.operationValue.value;
  let thisOperationName = operation.operationName.value;
  let thisEuroValue = parseFloat(operation.euroValue.value);

  let calcResoult = calcCurrency(thisEuroValue, thisOperationValue);
  let newOperation = document.createElement('tr');

  newOperation.innerHTML = `
  <td>${thisOperationName}</td>
  <td class="amountToChange">${thisOperationValue}</td>
  <td class="resultValue">${calcResoult.toFixed(2)} PLN</td>
  <input type="button" value="X" onclick="removeRow(this)" id="deleteBtn"/>`;
  const btns = resultList.getElementsByTagName('input');
  const delBtns = Array.from(btns);
  for( let i = 0; i < delBtns.length; i++) {
    delBtns[i].setAttribute('click', 'removeRow(this)');
  }

  resultList.appendChild(newOperation);

});

function calcCurrency(eValue, quantity) {
  return quantity * eValue;
}

function updateValues() {
  const outComePLN = Array.from( document.getElementsByClassName('resultValue'));
  const outComeEur = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('amountToChange'));
  for(let i = 0; i < outComePLN.length; i++) {
    outComePLN[i].innerHTML = (outComeEur[i].innerHTML * operation.euroValue.value).toFixed(2);
  }
};

function removeRow(btn) {
  const thisTable = document.getElementById('tableBody');
  thisTable.deleteRow(btn.parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex);
}
});
```

and HTML:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
      <title>Klkulator walut</title>
    </head>
    <body>
  <style>
    #cantor{
      margin: 10vh auto 0 auto;
      border: 1px solid black;
      width: 50%;
      min-height: 300px;
    }
  </style>
  <div id="cantor">
    <p>1 &euro; = <input type="text" value="4.14" id="euroValue">PLN</p>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Nazwa operacji" id="operationName">
    <input type="text" placeholder="ilość &euro;" id="operationValue">
    <input type="submit" placeholder="Oblicz" id="operationConfirm">
    <table id="results">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Nazwa operacji</th>
          <th>Kwota &euro;</th>
          <th>Kwota PLN</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody id="tableBody">
      </tbody>
    </table>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

And here's codepen:

https://codepen.io/jkarkosza/pen/qpoBEv?editors=1010

Comment: Codepen is empty. Use the button with the icon:`<>` so that your code can be copied over to an answer.

Comment: I've edited original post, it's working now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just move the `function removeRow(btn)`-Definition out of the EventListener-Definition. When you create a function inside that scope it will not be visible outside that function.

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
   [...]
});

function removeRow(btn) {
  const thisTable = document.getElementById('tableBody');
  thisTable.deleteRow(btn.parentNode.rowIndex-1);
}
```

Comment: Any idea why the it's deleting first element of the list instead of "this" element?

Comment: btn.parentNode.parentNode is undefined, i have fixed the code sample so it works

Answer (score 1):

Just declare the `removeRow` method outside the `addEventLister`. It works.

On clicking the button, it looks for the function in the global scope. So you need to declare globally.